# How to call function with parameter and stop previous one in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a function called List() with a String parameter.
I want to call it with different parameters when user change the menu, and it seems to work.

But the problem is that when I call List() for second time, the previous one's result still there.
How can I clear that previous function to not be shown when the second one called?

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.list_users:
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.user_list);
            List("OD12");
            return true;
        case R.id.list_users2:
            setContentView(R.layout.user_list);
            List("OD14");
            return true;
        case R.id.homepage:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what does List() do? post its snippet.

Comment: making a Get request with the help of Volley, then it puts the values into an array

Comment: post the code how you saving in array after getting response from volley.

Comment: you can clear the current chosen layout child-views by calling myLayoutObj.removeAllViews() before  setContentView() calls and then set the newly chosen layout. as for the values inside the array, if you don't want them, clear them using clear() if it's an ArrayList or accordingly.

Comment: I solved finally, I just have to clear the adapter for the listview.
Sorry for not being specific, quite knew to android

Comment: In your method List reset the String parameter in the very first row/step like private void List(String string){//reset string string=""; //and then do anything else with string}